# Saving Multiple File path to mysql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, file, upload

Good Day. I have a php script that move multiple file in my directory..

```
$filepath = 'uploads/';
if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
 $file_id = $_POST['file_id'];
 $count = 0;
foreach($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $k => $tmp_name){
 $name = $_FILES['file']['name'][$k];
 $size = $_FILES['file']['size'][$k];
 if (strlen($name)) {
        $extension = substr($name, strrpos($name, '.')+1);
        if (in_array(strtolower($extension), $file_formats)) { // check it if it's a valid format or not
 if ($size < (2048 * 1024)) { // check it if it's bigger than 2 mb or no
                $filename = uniqid()."-00000-". $name;=
                $tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$k];
                if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $filepath . $filename)) {
 $id = $file_id;
                    $file_path_array = array();
                    $files_path = $filepath . $filename;
                    $file_extension = $extension;
                        foreach($file_name as $k_file_path => $v_file_path){
                            $file_path_array[] = $v_file_path;
                        }
                        foreach($file_extension as $k_file_extension){
                            $file_extension_array[] = $v_file_extension;
                        }
                        $file_path = json_encode($files_path);
                        $file_name = str_replace("\/", "/",$file_path);
                        var_dump($file_name);
  $update = $mysqli->query("UPDATE detail SET file_path='$file_name' WHERE id='$id'");
                } else {
                    echo "Could not move the file.";
                }
            } else {
                echo "Your file is more than 2MB.";
            }
        } else {
                echo "Invalid file format PLEASE CHECK YOU FILE EXTENSION.";
        }
     } else {
        echo "Please select FILE";
     }
   }
    exit();
 }
```

this is my php script that move file to 'uploads/' directory and i want to save the path to my database. i try to dump the $file_name and this is my example path how to save that to my database.. ? any suggestions ?

NOTE: i already move the file to uploads/ directory and i only want to save the path to my database

```
string(46) "uploads/5638067602b48-00000-samplePDF.pdf" 
string(46) "uploads/5638067602dee-00000-samplePDF1.pdf" 
string(46) "uploads/5638067602f8d-00000-samplePDF2.pdf"
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with the `UPDATE` you currently have?

Comment: if you have multiple files associated with the one id, you should have a new table with `cscart_inquiry_detail_id | file_path`

Comment: @Dagon, is it possible that save the path like this format `[{"uploads/5638067602b48-00000-samplePDF.pdf", "uploads/5638067602b48-00000-samplePDF1.pdf", "uploads/5638067602b48-00000-samplePDF2.pdf"}]`

Comment: yes, but generally considered to be a bad idea

Comment: @Memor-X i already update my Update query.

Comment: @why Bad idea ? i want to save it in that format so that it is dynamic to the my upload.

Comment: @Jayson i'm assuming your `$file_name` varibale is an array (otherwise why does it output 3 strings in `var_dump`) in which case i would suggest `foreach($file_name as $data)` and running your query there. however if what @Dragon has seen is right and you have multiple files associated with the one id in the database it's best you make a new table and give them a separate id each.

Comment: bad idea because: [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Answer (score 0):

if you must store them in one field..

inside the loop

```
$file_name_for_db[]=$file_name;
```

outside the loop:

```
  $update = $mysqli->query("UPDATE detail SET file_path='".json_encode($file_name_for_db)."' WHERE id='$id'");
```

there is `serialize()` instead of `json_encode()` if you prefer